# Powerful and fast hash function in python (Search algorithm)

Tags: python, algorithm, hash, hashtable, robustness

Python has a default searching function which is:

```
x in [x,y,z,]
```

Where x,y,z can be any integers or characters, but this is a default sequential search and I want to know how I can use a manual hashing search in python.

Comment: "[x if x.getHashKeyMethod()==y.getHashKeyMethod() for x in myIterable]" will return all the objects with same hash as y from myIterable, is that it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`set()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) instead:

```
x in {x,y,z}
```

This uses a hash table under the hood, so searches are O(1).

Comment: hmmm, is this another built-in python function?

Comment: Yes, I linked you to the documentation for sets. Sets are a standard type.

Comment: Whoa, I just learned about the `{1,2,3}` notation for sets. Has it always been there? I must have missed it...

Comment: It is new in Python 2.7 and 3.x.